# How to skip private videos on a YouTube playlist embed

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

We're using the following code to embed the latest YouTube video in one of our playlists. We've queued a video up to go live tomorrow, and now our website is displaying a "video unavailable - Video Private" error. We checked the API but I don't see any playerVars that would skip private videos.

Any idea how to get a basic Youtube playlist to skip private or un-embedable videos?

```
        <div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>

        <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script>
         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          var player;
          player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
            width: 940,               // Player width (in px)
            height: 530,              // Player height (in px)
            playerVars: {
              listType:'playlist',
              list: '{{LIST_ID}}',
              autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
              controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
              showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
              modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
              loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
              fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
              cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
              iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
              autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
            },
            events: {
              onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.mute();
              }
            }
          });
         }
        </script>
```

I've also tried adding a bit to play the next video if there's an error. It changes to the next item in the playlist, but doesn't play it.

```
        <div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>

        <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script>
         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          var player;
          player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
            width: 940,               // Player width (in px)
            height: 530,              // Player height (in px)
            playerVars: {
              listType:'playlist',
              list: '{{LIST_ID}}',
              autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
              controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
              showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
              modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
              loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
              fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
              cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
              iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
              autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
            },
            events: {
              onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.mute();
              },
              onError: function(e){
                e.target.nextVideo();
                e.target.playVideo();
              }
            }
          });
         }
        </script>
```

Comment: I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/zrkfb29L/) that might help you. comparing your code and the jsfiddle, I saw that you can remove the `e.target.playVideo();` from the `onError` function. I also suggestion create a jsfiddle for reproduce the problem. Thanks