# Playlist fails to load entirely if there are privated or deleted videos in the list

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

While trying to implement the infamous YouTube Iframe API on a website I recently started to experience errors when loading new playlists due to the presence of videos that can't be play anymore because they are either hidden or deleted.

If the hidden or deleted video is the first in the playlist, the player will refuse to load entirely instead of skipping the faulty item, while if you manually swap order of the videos and say, move it to 2nd place in the list, it correctly skips the unavailable video and the playlist is loaded correctly. Sadly this fix is only temporary because if you load a completely unrelated playlist via the cuePlaylsit() call and then load back the first list with the unavailable video still in the 2nd place in the list, the playlist will once again fail to load but this time letting you see a preview of the playlist that just failed to load which show as second item the faulty video that was originally skipped when I loaded the first playlist at the very beginning..

I tried rewriting my code multiple times during these days but the only conclusion here is the API is once again bugged and I have no idea of how to plan a workaround for it

I tried isolating the issue here so you can try it for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/mytL2dka/

Simply swap first and second elements in the first array and try rerunning the fiddle. The playlist should be now correctly loaded. After that you can just toy with the buttons at the top cycling between second, third and first array and you should be able to notice the issue when clicking on the menu icon which normally shows you the content of the loaded playlist. I've seen another person posting about youtube videos not loading properly while browsing the youtube-iframe-api tag but I wasn't able to comment due to lack of reputation. I just hope that adding more questions about the same topic will give the bug more visibility.

```
let player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: '512',
    height: '288',
    playerVars: {
      'playlist': myArray.toString(),
    }
  });
}

const myArray = ["list", "of", "ids"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, glad to have you there, please read this how to ask a question section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Instead of blaming youtube's api, could you show us some errors you got ?

Comment: See the comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774243/how-to-skip-private-videos-on-a-youtube-playlist-embed

Comment: I would if there was anything to show, I hope you did read my post and tried testing my code in jsfiddle, There's no error in the console and no error when you try to output with the builtin event handling errors. The player simply fails to load. So yes, I am blaming youtube's api considering it's not the first bug I and other people complain about (read comment in my jsfiddle link if you're curious

Comment: Also @mplungjan thank you for the link but I think it won't be of much use to me since, in my case, I can't use the error event to skip videos

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.