# How skip unavailable video in Youtube iframe generated playlist

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a simple full window HTML document that plays all videos from one channel one after another. Every now and then, a video is unavailable within an iframe and it sits on "video unavailable, watch on youtube".
How can I make the playlist skip these videos and continue? I'm trying to get like a TV channel effect, for Wallpaper Engine.
the entire code is:
(old version)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=GameTrailers&autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&fs=0&color=white&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&controls=1&rel=0&mute=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the updated version found with a link from Benjamin Loison:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>

        <script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script>
         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          var player;
          player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
            width: 1366,               // Player width (in px)
            height: 768,              // Player height (in px)
            playerVars: {
              listType:'user_uploads',
              list: 'GameTrailers',
              autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
              controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
              showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
              modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
              loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
              fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
              cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
              iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
              autohide: 1         // Hide video controls when playing
            },
            events: {
              onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.mute();
              },
              onError: function(e){
                e.target.nextVideo();
                e.target.playVideo();
              }
            }
          });
         }
        </script>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I now just need to figure out how to make this fit window 100% instead of set pixel width, which I'm struggling with.

Comment: Could you precise a video id/playlist index from a video which is unavailable in your playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUJx5KP-pCUmL9eZUv-mIcNw ?

Comment: This one is an example of one that doesn't play in an iframe, taken from your link there:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8ZVxDK11Jo&list=UUJx5KP-pCUmL9eZUv-mIcNw&index=6

Comment: but the problem is too, the playlist always changes. somehow I managed to make it generate from a channel so whenever they upload it changes the order. I saw in the API there's an OnError thing but I have no clue how that works

Comment: "the playlist always changes" the playlist id you provided is an "uploads" playlist so the channel can only add videos at the beginning, I don't understand why it is a problem for you. As [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) doesn't work properly for the `status` > `embeddable` parameter I propose you to use some JavaScript and my YouTube operationnal API at https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=status&id=J8ZVxDK11Jo It will tell you that this video isn't embeddable while for instance this one is embeddable QXp8RcObYSs Does it help you solve your problem ?

Comment: Furthermore maybe this SO question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774243/how-to-skip-private-videos-on-a-youtube-playlist-embed

Comment: Oh WOW! the link in your last comment is so close to what I need! it skips unavailable videos automatically! exactly what I needed! Only problem now though, it has width and height in px, not in percentage. any ideas how I could get this new code to fit 100% width and height with no border? I've updated my question with the new code so far.
thank you for all your help so far! ♥

Answer (score 0):

Switch `width` value to `window.innerWidth` (instead of 1366) and `height` to `window.innerHeight` (instead of 768). Next time please deepen more on your own, I got all your answers by searching on StackOverflow...